# Javascript/Typescript default order sorting

Tags: typescript, sorting

I'm trying to learn typescript and I wanna learn why in this code I provided here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpVMJX. The test array changed order after I sorted it although I assigned the result to res variable. I assumed because the sorting automatically changes the sorted array. But I also tried to copy the original array to another variable (defaultArr) before sorting and it also changed its order.

```
let arr:any = [
            { count: 13, year: '1956' },
            { count: 1, year: '1971' },
            { count: 23, year: '1989' },
            { count: 11, year: '1988' }];
let defaultArr = arr;
async function foo(){
  console.log(defaultArr);
  console.log(arr);
  let res = arr.sort((n1,n2)=> n1.count > n2.count? -1:1);
  console.log(res); 
}
foo();
```

How can I make it behave like the original array will not change its order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assumed because the sorting automatically changes the sorted array.

Correct, `sort` changes the array you call it on. The return value is just a reference to the same array (for convenience).

> But I also tried to copy the original array to another variable (defaultArr) before sorting and it also changed its order.

You didn't copy the array, you just copied the *reference* to the array. You ended up with both `arr` and `defaultArr` pointing to the *same* array object:

```
arr[Ref:55461]−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                          |   +−−−−−−−−−+
                          +−−>| (array) |
                          |   +−−−−−−−−−+
defaultArr[Ref:55461]−−−−−+
```

to copy the *array*, you can use `slice`:

```
defaultArr = arr.slice();
```

---

A couple of other notes:

- There's no reason for `foo` to be `async`, it doesn't do any asynchronous work.
- Your `sort` callback is incorrect, it doesn't handle the case where the counts are equal.

Here's your example updated to copy the array, make `foo` not `async`, and correct the `sort` callback (see inline comments for details):

```js
let arr = [
            { count: 13, year: '1956' },
            { count: 1, year: '1971' },
            { count: 23, year: '1989' },
            { count: 11, year: '1988' }];
// No reason for this to be `async`
function foo(){
  let res = arr.slice();
  // The `sort` return value should be less than zero if n1 should come before n2,
  // greater than zer if n1 should come after n2,
  // or zero if they're equivalent for sorting purposes.
  // n2.count - n1.count gives us exactly that number, so we can use that directly
  res.sort((n1,n2) => n2.count - n1.count);
  console.log(res); 
}
foo();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know arrays behave like that.

Comment: @CedricManacob - You're not the only one. :-) All objects do in JavaScript. (Arrays are objects.) What you have in the variable is a *reference* to the object rather than the object itself. In your example, it's useful to remember that the array's entries are also references to the objects, not the objects themselves. So when you copy the array, you're just copying the references. The entries at `arr[0]` and `defaultArr[0]` after the call to `slice` both refer to the **same** object (with year = 1956).

Comment: @CedricManacob - I realized I got distracted by something and didn't address some other issues I saw in the code, so I've done that now. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you. As you said, the slice does not completely copy the array entries. I have researched a bit and found out that I can use JSON.parse then stringify to clone the array for simple arrays which does not have methods or constructors.

Comment: @CedricManacob - It's not that `slice` "does not completely copy the array entries," it doesn't copy them *at all*, just references to them. Don't use `JSON.parse` to clone object trees. If you need to do that, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).